# Cloning a SSD to an ISO on a USB

Tags: usb, iso-image, dd

I have a micro controller with an external SSD, running Ubunto, and I want to create a complete clone to a USB stick. Size isn't a problem.  I have 60 gigs on my target and only 8 gigs of data.

I know I can use dd to make clones and to make iso, but can I clone directly to an iso?

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1/backup.iso bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

Comment: Actually, dd cannot *make* an ISO image. Unless the source already *is* an ISO image or medium. ISO9660 is a CD filesystem and most definitely not what you want. What’s your goal with the backup?

Comment: This my last ditch, "the SSD just went up in smoke," backup.  Once I have this, I'll use Rsync to make incremental backups as the system changes.

Comment: unique method that I've been messing with, dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip > backup.iso.gz. then simply zcat > /dev/[your location] to extract/write... I should note that I've been doing it specifically for .raw.gz extensions but maybe it will work with .iso as well. I don't see why it wouldnt! and honestly I'm going to give it a shot now to see if the outcome is any different!

Answer (score 0):

Use mkisofs

`mkisofs -o /home/linuxlookup/example.iso /source/directory/`

This will create a iso file at `/home/linuxlookup/example.iso`, containing the files in `/source/directory/`

Comment: Will that give me the MBR as well?  The vendor didn't supply a recovery disk.  I'm trying to create my "the SSD just smoked itself," backup.